# Batching data from a temp table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I create a temp table, insert data (and output) and select. I need to batch them and read.

Example: If I have 110 records,and I want to read a batch of 50 records each time, then I will have read 1-50 the first time, 51-100 the second time and 100-110 the third time.

The queries are as follows

```
create table #mytable 
{
customerID int not null
} 
insert into #mytable(id)
Output inserted.CustomerID
select top 50 customerID from customer where customerID not in (select c.customerID from #mytable c)
```

In C#, I my code is like this

```
do {
    getCustomerInformation() //this method does the query processing
} while(customerInfo.Any());
```

this query works when I run it on SQL server but not in C#. Keeps returning the first 50 rows all the time.

Comment: add code of getCustomerInformation

Answer (score 0):

There are ways ..

1. From SQL Server 2012, we can use OFFSET and FETCH NEXT Clause to achieve the pagination.

   [Try this:](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23811.paging-a-query-with-sql-server.aspx)

2 For all version of sql post 2005  we can achieve the same with CTE and passing Param  [more detals](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/)

Answer (score 0):

simple use this query ,

1) First time @PageNumber parameter will be 1 ,
2nd time will be 2 and third time send 3

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT, @RowspPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber = 1 -- 2 , 3
SET @RowspPage = 50
SELECT customerID FROM (
             SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS Numero,
                    customerID FROM customer
               ) AS TBL
WHERE Numero BETWEEN ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowspPage + 1) AND (@PageNumber * @RowspPage)
ORDER BY customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, you have your temp table, and you check the IDs for your batch by checking the temp table.

Temp tables normally only live as long as the session. So if in C# you initialize a new session each time you call the method, your session will not see the temp table from the previous session.

You can get around this using ##two hashes, or just create an actual staging table.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve paging in C# using the `Take()` and `Skip()` methods provided by LINQ:

```
const int batchSize = 50;
do {
    var currentBatch = customerInfo.Take(batchSize);
    customerInfo = customerInfo.Skip(batchSize);
} while(customerInfo.Any());
```